# flywheel diode for radio transmitter and receiver need? or not?

Tags: transistors, switches, inductor

I am a building a device for communicate each other devices via radio signals (VHF) then I want to switch off and on Radio transmitter and receiver driven by 5V max.

transmitter = 24  mA 
Receiver = 11  mA

then i decided to transistor switches for this and I heard  flywheel diodes need to prevent effects on EMF s . then radio system generate EMF always when it work.

so transistor switch and radio equip. in same PCB. Actually do we need flywheel diodes for this circuit.if it need,is IN 4007 diode suitable for this?

Transmitter and receiver data sheet -

[Data Sheet](http://data.datasheetlib.com/pdf1/113/69/1136953/rfsolutions-ltd-r7g-434-075_a86f653e39.pdf?take=binary)

[image]

Comment: Probably not and probably not, but you'll get a better answer if you show us your proposed schematic and link to the parts datasheets. There may be other problems.

Comment: I add schematic of transmitter and also this switch fit to receiver

Comment: Unlikely, but you need a schematic/break open/understanding if the input stage of your transceiver to tell for sure. You diode isn't hurting anything anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Extremely unlikely that you need the diode, however you should be using a high-side switch (don't break the RF ground) and there may be a problem if you are applying a non-zero signal to the data in pin with no power applied.

Consider changing to a high-side switch, adding a series resistor of perhaps 4.7K and a Schottky diode from data in to the transmitter supply Vcc.

See other examples in SE for high-side switches, there are many.